# Can we write multiple queries in a MySQL event?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I want to execute the following queries with help of Mysql event But when I add the delete statement in the event and try to create it, gives me Mysql Error. If I chose to skip the delete statement the event gets created without any problem.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bookings_released
(
    id, row, seatnum, price,theatre_id, play_id, show_id, showtime, show_date, 
    isbooked, inserted_at, inserted_from, booking_num, tot_price, subzone_id, 
    zone_id, txn_id
)
SELECT 
    id, row, seatnum, price,theatre_id, play_id, show_id, showtime, 
    show_date, isbooked, inserted_at, inserted_from, booking_num, 
    tot_price, subzone_id, zone_id, txn_id
FROM tbl_bookings
WHERE (
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inserted_at )
) /60 > 2
AND booking_num NOT
IN (
    SELECT booking_id
    FROM tbl_cust_booking
);

DELETE
FROM tbl_bookings
WHERE (
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inserted_at )
) /60 > 2
AND booking_num NOT
IN (
    SELECT booking_id
    FROM tbl_cust_booking
);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an example modified from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) that execute multiple queries for an event:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Saves total number of sessions then clears the table each day'
    DO
      BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_bookings_released
    (
        id, row, seatnum, price,theatre_id, play_id, show_id, showtime, show_date, 
        isbooked, inserted_at, inserted_from, booking_num, tot_price, subzone_id, 
        zone_id, txn_id
    )
    SELECT 
        id, row, seatnum, price,theatre_id, play_id, show_id, showtime, 
        show_date, isbooked, inserted_at, inserted_from, booking_num, 
        tot_price, subzone_id, zone_id, txn_id
    FROM tbl_bookings
    WHERE (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inserted_at )
    ) /60 > 2
    AND booking_num NOT
    IN (
        SELECT booking_id
        FROM tbl_cust_booking
    );

    DELETE
    FROM tbl_bookings
    WHERE (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inserted_at )
    ) /60 > 2
    AND booking_num NOT
    IN (
        SELECT booking_id
        FROM tbl_cust_booking
    );


      END |

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was using phpmyadmin to create event and in the definition text area I had just written my desired queries without BEGIN and END tags, I guess that was the problem. I edited my existing event to add BEGIN and END and it worked!

Comment: If the insert fails, will the delete be executed?

Answer (score 20):

if you are using phpmyadmin to create event then add multiple queries inside BEGIN and END tags
[image]

Comment: Note to self: Seems to only work with a blank line after BEGIN and before END

Comment: In MariaDB (PHPMyAdmin), BEGIN END is not working even I am giving black line after BEGIN and before END

Comment: This is my code :                                                                                         
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE EVENT test_event_03
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 72 HOUR
DO
BEGIN

   UPDATE complete_exam_set 
   SET live_status = '1' 
   WHERE test_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
   
   UPDATE complete_exam_set 
   SET live_status = '2' 
   WHERE end_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
   
END;
@@;
   
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE EVENT test_event_03
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 72 HOUR
DO
BEGIN

    UPDATE complete_exam_set 
   SET live_status = '1' 
   WHERE test_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

   UPDATE complete_exam_set 
   SET live_status = '2' 
   WHERE end_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

END;
@@;

DELIMITER ;
```

Why that **red cross** is coming near END
what's wrong?

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

You got the red x because you used the semicolon in the last line..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33715915)